# Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, yahoo

I am using codeigniter smtp mail for sending mails but I am getting the below error
The following SMTP error was encountered: Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

```
   Following is my code
    $message = 'THIS IS A TEST MAIL';
     $ci = get_instance();
     $ci->load->library('email');
     $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
     $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
     $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
     $config['smtp_user'] = "contact@domain.com";
     $config['smtp_pass'] = "*********";
     $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
     $config['mailtype'] = "html";
     $config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
     $config['newline'] = '\r\n';
     $ci->email->initialize($config);
     $ci->email->from('contact@domain.com', 'domain name');
     $list = array('*******@gmail.com');
     $ci->email->to($list);
     $this->email->reply_to('contact@domain.com', 'Explendid Videos');
     $ci->email->subject('This is an email test');
     $ci->email->message($message);
     if ($ci->email->send()) {
        echo 'Your email was sent.';
     } else {
        show_error($ci->email->print_debugger());
     }
```

Comment: i didn't get u ? can u please explain where i need to run this command

Comment: Build your config as suggested here : https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/132443/#653650

Comment: @AdrienXL working fine....thank you so much for the answer...was struggling with it from weeks